# Apache Avro - Write Serialized data to stream

Tags: python, avro

Im building a short example of apache avro with python, following this doc:
(https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedpython.html)

```
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

schema = avro.schema.parse(open("user.avsc", "rb").read())

writer = DataFileWriter(open("users.avro", "wb"), DatumWriter(), schema)
writer.append({"name": "Alyssa", "favorite_number": 256})
    writer.append({"name": "Ben", "favorite_number": 7, "favorite_color": "red"})
writer.close()
```

Pretty simple use case, but I'm new to python and I'm struggling to find a way to write the avro result to a stream instead of a file.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

Python has an [`io` module in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) that should be able to help with this. Since avro is a binary format, you'll want to import `BytesIO from the`io module. You can then use that like an open file handle to a binary file.

So you would change:

```
writer = DataFileWriter(open("users.avro", "wb"), DatumWriter(), schema)
```

To:

```
from io import BytesIO
bio = BytesIO()
writer = DataFileWriter(bio, DatumWriter(), schema)
```